# how to add up the elements of list s with even indexes in one line?

Tags: python

I am learning python and couldn't figure it out. I got to this point and am stumped.

```
def func5(s):
    return [s for i in range(len(s)) if i % 2 == 0]
```

in: `print(func5([1, 2, 3, 4]))`

out: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`

It shouldn't show that way of course. Elements with even indexes must be added to all elements.

in ---> [1, 2, 3, 4]

out---> [5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: What do you mean by "Elements with even indexes must be added to all elements."? What exactly is your expected output for `s=[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: I can't understand "Elements with even indexes must be added to all elements." . There are two elements with event indices. Looking to `out` you want to add the element with biggest even index?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to decipher what your actual end-result should be, because you haven't really explained the logic fully in your question.

My answer will be based on my own understanding of your description, which follows:

> For each integer in list `s`, add the sum of the indexes of all even
> values of `s`. Do this all using a one-liner function.

Using your example of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, we can check what values should summed:

```
>>> [(idx, val) for idx, val in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4]) if val%2 == 0]
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

So for that list, we should add `sum(1,3)` to each integer.

Before we create a "one-liner" to solve the problem, let's create a more "verbose" solution of the problem:

```
def evenIndexes(int_list):
    evenIntSum = sum([idx for idx, i in enumerate(int_list) if i % 2 == 0])
    new_int_list = []
    for integer in int_list:
        new_int_list.append(evenIntSum + integer)
    return new_int_list
```

Which you can immediately shorten to two list-comprehensions instead, to create a two liner:

```
def evenIndexes(int_list):
    evenIntSum = sum([idx for idx, i in enumerate(int_list) if i % 2 == 0])
    return  [integer + evenIntSum for integer in int_list]
```

Now that is already quite compact but if you want to compact it even further, then you will have to nest the two list-comprehensions:

```
def evenIndexes(int_list):
    return [i + sum([idx for idx, _ in enumerate(int_list) if _ % 2 == 0]) for i in int_list]
```

However, keep in mind that the above piece of code "summarizes" all of the even indexes once for each integer in the original list instead of just using the already calculated value like the other versions does. That means that the larger that list grows, the more inefficient the loop becomes.

Here are some random examples of the code running:

```
Original List: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Iterated List: [5, 6, 7, 8]

Original List: [61, 46, 86, 10, 68]
Iterated List: [71, 56, 96, 20, 78]

Original List: [33, 96, 34, 96, 95]
Iterated List: [39, 102, 40, 102, 101]

Original List: [92, 13, 44, 57, 71]
Iterated List: [94, 15, 46, 59, 73]

Original List: [18, 45, 20, 16, 66]
Iterated List: [27, 54, 29, 25, 75]
```